# wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) hartl tutorial chapter 9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I clicked on the users tab for my sample_app and I got the error wrong number of arguments (2 for 1).

index.html.erb

said the error was with the line of code  <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>

```
 <ul class="users">
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <li>
        <%= gravatar_for user, size: 52 %>
        <%= link_to user.name, user %>
      </li>
    <% end %>
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]

 def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
def edit
  end

def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

 private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Before filters

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

 def sign_in(user)
    remember_token = User.new_remember_token
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
    user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.encrypt(remember_token))
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

    def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    remember_token = User.encrypt(cookies[:remember_token])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(remember_token: remember_token)
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end

  def redirect_back_or(default)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default)
    session.delete(:return_to)
  end

   def store_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url if request.get?
  end
end
```

users_helper.rb

```
module UsersHelper

  # Returns the Gravatar (http://gravatar.com/) for the given user.
  def gravatar_for(user)
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}"
    image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
  end
end
```

I know I must have missed some line of code and or misspelled something somewhere. Anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're passing in options into the `gravatar_for` method. Add a second parameter to your method definition called `options = {}`. Then use those options to tailor your gravatar request. I think that's how he does it in the tutorial.